# Como permitir ao usuário selecionar um diretório/pasta usando um FileChooserDialog?

Tags: c, gtk

Talvez possa adicionar um filtro de diretório para conseguir isso.

Comment: Eu tirei algumas *tags* desnecessárias para o problema. Você está usando C mesmo? Ou C++? Ou é um ou outro. Não sei se entendi. Uma das funções deste diálogo é justamente deixar o usuário selecionar uma pasta. Vou tentar responde com o que eu entendi.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Você provavelmente teria que usar o método `set_action` com a opção de filtro correta. Algo assim:

```
seuDialogo.set_action(gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER)
```

Tem [um exemplo aqui](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-dialogs-filechooserdialog.html.en) em C++.

```
Gtk::FileChooserDialog dialog("Please choose a folder", Gtk::FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Library/Gtk.c).